Does a sequence of random seeds generate a pseudo-random sequence?
Sorry for the convoluted title. Basically, my question is: can we say that the sequence produced by the following sequence() function is pseudo-random?
import numpy as np

def sequence(int n):
    x = np.empty(n, dtype=int)
    for i in range(n):
        np.random.seed(i)
        x[i] = np.random.randint(100)
    return x

Note that the seed is set every time before sampling one (pseudo)random integer, not just once before generating all the samples, but the seed changes every time.
For a bit of context, the reason why I am interested in knowing this is that I need to generate a set of objects, each of which needs to sample a set of properties. Each object has a given ID (a progressive integer) and I thought I could use it as seed to instanciate a random number generator for each object. This would ensure that each instance is "reproducible by ID". For sake of example, say that the objects represent people and the first property sampled every time is their age. If the answer to my original question is "no, sequence() does not produce a pseudo-random array", then it would mean that the sequence of ages generated for a list of people would not be pseudo-random - which is precisely what I want to avoid!

Older random number generators were highly correlated to the seed for the first couple of random numbers they generated.  I'm not sure about newer ones (like numpy's) but I wouldn't assume they're not correlated too.

That's a bummer, but honestly it is what I would have expected... :')

It isn’t guaranteed to be pseudorandom. Some particularly weak RNGs, such as many LCGs, use the seed directly as the internal state, which means that the first few outputs will be highly correlated to the seed. More sophisticated algorithms, like MT19937, feature a seeding algorithm that will randomize the state to some extent.
However, if your goal is to create good random numbers from a sequence of “seeds”, one approach is to seed an RNG using a strong hash of your input. For example:
from hashlib import sha256

SEQUENCE_SALT = "some-random-string" # some fixed, arbitrary string used to make your seeds unique

h = sha256((SEQUENCE_SALT + str(i)).encode()).digest() 
np.random.seed(int.from_bytes(h))
# generate random numbers…

This will be a bit slower than just using seed directly, but the use of a strong hash function will effectively guaranteed that the output is unbiased.
